# Clicking on an empty line in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I just switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ, and I'm liking it so far. The only problem I've had is that if I click in the middle of an empty line and start typing, the text will actually appear on the middle of the line, instead of the correct indentation. Is there any way to fix this so that is works like Eclipse. No matter where I click on an empty line, I want to start typing where I'm "supposed" to.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12, and if I recall correctly I didn't have this problem when I tried 11 (this might be wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click File -> Settings -> Editor -> Virtual Space and uncheck 'Allow placement of caret after end of line'. This should help.